# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) . issue occured in streamlit app

Tags: python, json

I am making a neural network visualizer web app using python, but when I run the code for streamlit app, it keeps showing me this json decode error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The code:

```py
import streamlit as st
import json
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

URI = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'

st.title('Neural Network Visualizer')
st.sidebar.markdown('## Input Image')

if st.button('Get random prediction'):
    response = requests.post(URI, data={})
    response = json.loads(response.text)
    preds = response.get('prediction')
    image = response.get('image')
    image = np.reshape(image, (28, 28))
    
    st.image(image, width=150)
```

Comment: what does `response.text` look like? put a `print` statement right after the line `response = requests.post(URI, data={})`

Comment: It might happen if your request is not successful. Did you check your response's status code?

Comment: Putting a print statement doesn't show anything. It shows same error of jsondecodeerror

Comment: It means your server is not returning any values.